# One of My URL parameter having Turkish characters change to Unicode when link click and open new window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

when the user click link bellow;

```
<input name="Button2" id="Button2" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;" onclick="javascript:location.href=&quot;auto.aspx?ID=0&amp;KartID=18&amp;MusteriID=1323&amp;SirketID=100000001&amp;UserAlias=Çağdş&amp;Default=335520&amp;LinkType=siparis&amp;LinkID=335520&quot;" type="button" value="Open Purchase Order">
```

"UserAlias" parameter of new window url like this; Turkish characters of UserAlias value change to unicode characters. How can I solve this problem ?

```
http://localhost:3170/crm/auto.aspx?ID=0&KartID=18&MusteriID=1323&SirketID=100000001&UserAlias=%C7a%F0d%FE&Default=335520&LinkType=siparis&LinkID=335520
```

Comment: That is how a URL works

Answer (score 0):

Let it encode your url, you can decode it when you are consuming that value/param by decodeURIComponent in JavaScript.